# How to configure VS Code to run npx vite dev when debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, svelte, vscode-debugger

I am new to VS Code and JavaScript, and I am trying to make a simple app using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/), but I have a problem which I can't seem to resolve. (My code is currently just the default code given when a new project is created; I haven't changed it at all.)

When I run my app through Windows Terminal (by navigating to the project root directory and running `npx vite dev`), the app runs fine and my browser can connect to `localhost:3000`.

However, when I press on either:

- `Run > Start Debugging`, or
- `Run > Run Without Debugging`

in Visual Studio Code, it opens up Chrome to `localhost:3000` but I just see `localhost refused to connect`. I think VS Code is never actually running the command `npx vite dev`, but I don't know how to change this.

When I open up `.vscode/launch.json`, I see this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug with Chrome",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am not sure what I should add here to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question, but I couldn't fund any help searching Google or SO.

**EDIT:**

I have almost got this working by adding a `preLaunchTask`, but now chrome  no longer automatically opens when I start debugging, so I might as well just run `npm: dev` on its own.

Here is `.vscode/launch.json` now:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug with Chrome",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: dev"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think this might be because the `npm: dev` task (which effectively runs `npx vite dev`) is blocking, and only finishes when I press the stop button (or double-click ctrl+c), so chrome is not opened because VS Code thinks the pre-launch task is still running.

If there any way I can tell VS Code to open Chrome while continuing to run `npm: dev`?

Comment: Are you using SvelteKit or plain svelte?

Comment: @JudahB. Plain Svelte

Comment: Have you tried running `npm dev --open`? I'm not 100% percent sure if this will work since I've only used SvelteKit, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the [VSCode way](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_automatically-open-a-uri-when-debugging-a-server-program) to start the Vite Dev server (*npx vite*) and then automatically open Chrome and attach a debug session to it.

```json
// launch.json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Vite DEV server",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "vite",
      ],
      "type": "node",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "debugWithChrome",
        "pattern": "Local: http://localhost:([0-9]+)",
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s"
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Many things can be customized in the launch.json. I recommend you to read the documentation linked above.

The "magic" happends in "*serverReadyAction*" where you set the "*action*" to "*debugWithChrome*" to open chrome.

The "*pattern*" is a regex used to capture the port on which the server have been launched.

Finally, you add the port to the URL in the "*uriFormat*" by using %s.  %s represent the capture done with the regex in "*pattern*"

Comment: ⚠ If the output is colored, the color escape codes will affect your pattern.  For vite, I'm using `"pattern": "127\\.0\\.0\\.1:.*m([0-9]+)",` (escape the periods properly, and then skip the `ESC[123m` style color codes, then group match the port)

Comment: Thanks @nathan for the tip about ANSI colour escape codes - I had struggled for hours. For some reason I had to remove the \\ escape characters from the regex to make it work: `"pattern": "127.0.0.1:.*m([0-9]+)"` This on VS Code v1.74

Comment: It doesn't start Chrome for me. I am running Vite 4.x. (React with Typescritp)

Comment: it does run the browser for me after changing to `"pattern": "http://127.0.0.1:.*m([0-9]+)", "uriFormat": "http://127.0.0.1:%s"`.

Comment: In my case (Vite 4.2 and VSCode 1.78) it worked with this config:
```json
"pattern": "Local:   http://localhost:([0-9]+)/",
"uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having it run `npx vite dev` (which is the `npm: dev` task), have it run `npx vite dev --open` :)

Comment: Note: It should be `npx vite dev --open` not `npm dev --open`.

Comment: @Lecdi Noted :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (perhaps because I do remote development in `vscode`).

Here is what works for me:

1. Edit 'launch.json' to contain the following:

   ```
   {
     // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
     // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "type": "chrome",
         "request": "launch",
         "name": "Launch Chrome",
         "url": "http://localhost:5173",
         "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
         "sourceMaps": true,
         "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
             "${workspaceFolder}/**",
             "!**/node_modules/**"
         ],
       },
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Edit the "scripts" element of 'package.json' so that the "dev" item contains the following:

   ```
   "dev": "vite --host --open",
   ```
3. Since I develop on a remote system running Rocky Linux, I have to do the following (once) from a shell:

   ```
   sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5173/tcp
   ```

   Then restart the remote system (to make sure the port is actually open)

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

With the above changes, type the following command in the embedded terminal window to start the server:

```
yarn dev
```

This starts the development server, which listens on port 5173, and opens a Chrome development browser.

You can close the development browser and then reopen it with a click on the "Launch Chrome" button at the top of the "Run" view.

This solved the problem for me. I use remote development for everything, so I need a local Chrome development browser to connect (through its special VSCode port) to the remote server.

Good luck!